# file_exists with partial name... is it possible?

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if a file exists in two domains.

However, the format of the file that is written to the db doesnt match the one recorded on my directories, due to a few seconds delay. (examples below)

**Filename that actually exists**
https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/consulta_87314134987_02102017135619.pdf

**Result of my filename**
https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/consulta_87314134987_02102017135613.pdf

As you can see, there is a difference in the last two chars (representing the seconds) before the file extension.

```
$dir01 = "https://dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/";
$dir02 = "https://dominio02.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/";

$documento = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $item['retCNPJCPF']);
$dataDoc = new DateTime($item['retDataHora']);

$filename = "consulta_".$documento."_".$dataDoc->format('dmYHis').".pdf";

if(file_exists($dir01.$filename)){
    $lnkConsultas = "Available at dominio 01";
}
elseif(file_exists($dir02.$filename)){
    $lnkConsultas = "Available at domínio 02";
}
```

I would like to know if its possible to bring the files without inform the seconds, and return the occurrences of this. Maybe changing the filename with some regex, but i have no idea how to do that.

PS: I cant use "glob" functions. It will return blank results because the files are in another domains.

Comment: Just remove the "s" in the format() function ? $filename = "consulta_".$documento."_".$dataDoc->format('dmYHi').".pdf";

Comment: @Pauloscorps: Same problem when file1 ends with `5659` and file2 `5703` they are different even if you cut the seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file_exists can not do any kind of "searching". I would create simple API scripts on the 2 domains using "glob" to return found files as json based on your search pattern. You could actually invoke them straight from the front-end returning jsonp.

Comment: Interesting. This actually works! Thanks for the idea!